# Trigonometric equation $\cos9x=\cos3x$

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve equation $\cos9x=\cos3x$? I see that $\cos9x=\cos(3\times3x)$ but I think that this way require a lot of calculation and is not creative. What are your  suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean all solutions? $x=0$ is obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\cos A=\cos B$ if either $A=B+2k\pi$ or $A=-B+k2\pi$. Can you find the answer now?

---

If a more complicated formula is required, use

$$\cos(A)-\cos(B)=-2\sin\frac{A+B}2\sin\frac{A-B}2$$

Comment: $B=0$  and $A=2k\pi$  ?? if so then it's wrong  I think about substitution $9x=6x+3x$ and $3x=6x-3x$

Comment: What? Obviously, $A=3x$ and $B=9x$ is obtained by comparing with the question.

Comment: I don't know how to solve it using your first formula but using the second one I have $\sin6x\sin3x=0$  so further without problem. I would be greatful if you can elaborate the first method

Comment: $3x=\pm9x+2k\pi$ results in the same conditions, $3x=k\pi$ or $6x=k\pi$.

Comment: ok thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Note that $\cos 3y=\cos y\cos 2y-\sin y\sin 2y=\cos y(2\cos^2y-1)-2\sin^2 y\cos y=4\cos^3y-3\cos y$

So if $\cos 3y=\cos y$ we have $4\cos^3y-4\cos y=0$

You can solve this easily for $\cos y$, and hence $y$ and then put $y=3x$.